# How to handle load and configured tomcat 7 server and application, so it able to handle request more than 2000

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, webserver, connection-pooling

I have Apache tomcat web server, In this i am running 3-4 java spring and hibernate application. But the problem is when too many request come in server then server give error out of memory or heap size error and finally site going down due to server not responding.Also some time gives error like connection out or socket error. I want my server at least handle 2000 request.

Till now i implements lot of way to handle this problem.

1. Increase heap size of server by changing size in setenv.sh file

> CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true  -Dorg.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.ENABLE_CLEAR_REFERENCES=false -Duser.timezone=GMT -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m"

2. I have changed server.xml to handle to more connection

> acceptCount="1000" 
>                  maxConnections="1500"
>                  redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="UTF-8"
>                  compression="on"
>                  compressionMinSize="2048"
>                  noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata"
>                  compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/plain,application/javascript,text/javascript,text/css" />

3. Also i am using c3p0 connection pooling in our project

   org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider
       14400
       select 1;

   ```
   <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl</property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.username">xxx</property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.password">xxx</property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">1000</property>
   <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</property>
   <property name="javax.persistence.validation.mode">none</property>
   ```

But my server not able to handle more than 500 request simultaneously.
my server configuration is

> window server 2012 R2 Datacenter
>   Ram - 64 gb
>   system type-64 bit

Any idea how i manage all thing properly, what type changes i needed in my tomcat server or application. So that my site able to handle 2000 request.

Comment: if you have 64GB of Ram, why do you give tomcat only 1GB? (-Xmx1024m)?

Answer (score 0):

First you should found what's bottleneck on application(that depend on your scene), increase memory size, tomcat pool size and JDBC pool size maybe can improve performance, but not the real point.

1. Check which step cost so many time when process request? what's you web framework? struts2, restlet, springMVC, servelt ?
2. Analyse objects on heap using jvisualvm(or other tools), watching garbage collection time (full GC frequency), there's some slow code?
3. If have a lot of query, add L2 cache on hibernate.
4. What's server configuration, trying separate applications to multi tomcat instance (be careful shutdown port etc.).

Comment: I have Restful services, Spring MVC application, and simple jsp hibernate  application. Restful services use in user view site and mobile app . Spring MVC use for admin application. If  am using multi tomcat instance and separate restful services and admin module then how i manage multi tomcat because currently my tomcat running in port 80. if am using 2 tomcat instance then i am only able run 1 tomcat in port 80 that make all application live. My all application run under same domain name.

Comment: You want to increase restful service performance to mobile app? what's you restful service framework? jersey? mobile app request has DB query on service? if yes, you can trying remove DB query and doing a testing using jmeter (or others).  If you want to separate to 2 instance, you can trying use Ngnix as a proxy on different context but on same domain.

Answer (score -1):

To avoid memory issue (heap size error) why dont you increase the tomcat memory configuration?

Since you have 64G you can set memeory configuration as below:

> -Xmx50G -Xms10G

If you are using java8 just add GC algorithm to:

> -XX:+UseG1GC

Example:

> JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx50G
>   -Xms10G -XX:+UseG1GC"